# Bluetooth adapter won’t remember pairing and needs be re-paired again

Tags: bluetooth

I have a strange problem here. After pairing something, my Bluetooth adapter will not connect to what I paired unless I remove the device then re-pair it. Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

The OS I'm running on is Windows 10 64 bit, and it's a Bluetooth adapter under the brand zexmte. I've already gotten drivers for it from the disc it came with, and I still have the same problem.

The light on the adapter does not flash blue when nothing is connected or when I try to connect something my turning it on. Only when something is actively connected or I'm pairing something.

Comment: It shows Realtek Bluetooth 5.0 Adapter

Comment: It works, but I have to re-pair my devices to use them on my PC. There are no errors, the adapter just doesn't search for devices to connect to when I'm not trying to pair something.

Comment: It doesn't show up in there. Only my phone does from when I plugged it in wired.

Comment: Removable devices is only for flash drives and portable hard drives. It does not affect anything with my Bluetooth adapter.